React app doesn't display ASP.NET Core / EF Core database data, using Cors to access them (tutorial of Neil Cummings on REACT)
React front is on 3000 and my ASP.NET Core backend is on port 5000. React part has product definition and data fetching from localhost:5000/api and accessing data by prevState in AddProduct function. Based on the tutorial, I have cors to program.cs but I cannot make it work. When running the application, I get

This localhost page can't be found error 401.

Product.tsx
export interface Product {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  price: number;
  pictureUrl: string;
  type?: string;
  brand: string;
  quantityInStock?: number;
}

App.tsx
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Product } from './product';

function App() {
  const [products,setProducts] = useState<Product[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('htttp://localhost:5000/api/products')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => setProducts(data))
  },[])

  function addProduct() {
    setProducts(prevState => [...prevState,
      {
        id: prevState.length + 101,
        name: "product" + (prevState.length + 1),
        price: (prevState.length * 100) + 100,
        brand: 'some brand',
        description: 'some description',
        pictureUrl: 'http://picsum.photos/200',
      }])
}
 
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <h1>RESTORE</h1>
      <ul>
        {products.map(product=>(
          <li key={product.id}>{product.name} - {product.price}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <button onClick={addProduct}>Add product</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

Program.cs:
using API.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Operations;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        builder.Services.AddControllers();
        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
        builder.Services.AddDbContext<StoreContext>(opt =>
        {
            opt.UseSqlite(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        });
        builder.Services.AddCors();
        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
        }
        app.UseCors(opt =>
        {
            opt.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().WithOrigins("http:/localhost:3000");

        });
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.MapControllers();

        var scope = app.Services.CreateScope();
        var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<StoreContext>();
        var logger = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();

        try
        {
            context.Database.Migrate();
            DBInitializer.Initilize(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            logger.LogError(ex, "A problem occurred during migration");
        }

        app.Run();
    }
}

I have tried to check if my Cors correctly written and if referenced local port are correct.

In you asp.net core, you are using Authorization middleware. Is your /api/products decorated with [Authorize] attribute? Can you remove app.UseAuthorization() code and try testing it?

You have at least one mistake in your CORS configuration: there is a typo in http:/localhost:3000; it should be http://localhost:3000. Fix that and try again. A good CORS library would alert you to such easy mistakes, but .NET's CORS middleware does not, unfortunately.

Thank you for the help. Typo was fixed but still same problem. When removing app.UseAuthorization() code, no  changes neither.

also where you do fetch('htttp://localhost:5000/api/products'), there is an extra t in there.

Besides, Page not found should be http status code 404 instead of 401.

@EmreBener, I don't think on the line of fetch that there is additional 't' 'fetch('htttp://localhost:5000/api/products')'

@BarbraFlegel htttp needs to be http

You need to add Cors services, and then configure middleware to use the specified policy. For this, you can go with either named policies or setting a default policy.
Here is how you would add services while also specifying the settings as the default:
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(
      policy =>
      {
          policy
          .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000", "https://localhost:3000")
          .AllowAnyHeader()
          .AllowAnyMethod();
      });
});

The added services includes the CORS service itself, a default policy provider, and various options-related services.
After adding CORS services to the service container, register the middleware in pipeline:
// ...

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRouting(); // i am not sure where this needs to be, since you are using a JS client. it might have to go after Cors middleware. Please edit this if you find out how where this line needs to go. for systems without JS clients, it goes before Cors middleware.

app.UseCors(); // you dont have to specify a policy name since you configured a default policy.

app.UseStaticFiles(); // this needs to go after cors middleware since you are using a JS client. this is confirmed at microsoft docs.

app.UseAuthorization();

// ...


thank you, I will try your approach. the code works for the tutorial instructor so I wouldn't expect that the services must be added to AddCors

Unfortunatly this doesn't work neither.

@BarbraFlegel what's the error you see in console? can you inspect the network tab in devtools? the CORS setup is correct, the error must be something else
